# Vision API: How to get JSON-output

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I'm having trouble saving the output given by the Google Vision API. I'm using Python and testing with a demo image. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: [mid:...] + is not JSON serializable
```

Code that I executed:

```
import io
import os
import json
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

# Instantiates a client
vision_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()


# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'demo-image.jpg') # Your image path from current directory

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
    image = types.Image(content=content)

# Performs label detection on the image file
response = vision_client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations


print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description, label.score, label.mid)

with open('labels.json', 'w') as fp:
   json.dump(labels, fp)
```

the output appears on the screen, however I do not know exactly how I can save it. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

FYI to anyone seeing this in the future, google-cloud-vision 2.0.0 has switched to using proto-plus which uses different serialization/deserialization code. A possible error you can get if upgrading to 2.0.0 without changing the code is:

```
object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'
```

Using google-cloud-vision 2.0.0, protobuf 3.13.0, here is an example of how to serialize and de-serialize (example includes json and protobuf)

```py
import io, json
from google.cloud import vision_v1
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import AnnotateImageResponse

with io.open('000048.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision_v1.Image(content=content)
client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient()
response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)

# serialize / deserialize proto (binary)
serialized_proto_plus = AnnotateImageResponse.serialize(response)
response = AnnotateImageResponse.deserialize(serialized_proto_plus)
print(response.full_text_annotation.text)

# serialize / deserialize json
response_json = AnnotateImageResponse.to_json(response)
response = json.loads(response_json)
print(response['fullTextAnnotation']['text'])
```

*Note 1*: proto-plus doesn't support converting to snake_case names, which is supported in protobuf with `preserving_proto_field_name=True`. So currently there is no way around the field names being converted from `response['full_text_annotation']` to `response['fullTextAnnotation']`
There is an <s>open</s> closed feature request for this: [googleapis/proto-plus-python#109](https://github.com/googleapis/proto-plus-python/issues/109)

*Note 2*: The google vision api doesn't return an x coordinate if x=0. If x doesn't exist, the protobuf will default x=0. In python vision 1.0.0 using `MessageToJson()`, these x values weren't included in the json, but now with python vision 2.0.0 and `.To_Json()` these values are included as x:0

Comment: This is the actual solution. Anyone having trouble with converting google api response to json should simply look at this.

Comment: It's a shame that the google-cloud-vision 2.0.0 have no easy way of exporting to a json. Probably fine to use the vision_v1 code, but I'm edgy.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you were already able to find a solution to your issue (if that is the case, I invite you to share it as an answer to your own post too), but in any case, let me share some notes that may be useful for other users with a similar issue:

As you can check using the the `type()` function in Python, **`response`** is an object of [`google.cloud.vision_v1.types.AnnotateImageResponse` type](https://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vision/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.AnnotateImageResponse), while **`labels[i]`** is an object of [`google.cloud.vision_v1.types.EntityAnnotation` type](https://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vision/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.EntityAnnotation). None of them seem to have any out-of-the-box implementation to transform them to JSON, as you are trying to do, so I believe the easiest way to transform each of the `EntityAnnotation` in **`labels`** would be to turn them into Python dictionaries, then group them all into an array, and transform this into a JSON.

To do so, I have added some simple lines of code to your snippet:

```
[...]

label_dicts = [] # Array that will contain all the EntityAnnotation dictionaries

print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    # Write each label (EntityAnnotation) into a dictionary
    dict = {'description': label.description, 'score': label.score, 'mid': label.mid}

    # Populate the array
    label_dicts.append(dict) 

with open('labels.json', 'w') as fp:
   json.dump(label_dicts, fp)
```

Comment: Thank you to remind me :) I do have found an Answer and now posted.

Answer (score 3):

There is a library released by Google

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
```

`webdetect = vision_client.web_detection(blob_source)
    jsonObj = MessageToJson(webdetect)`

Comment: Any idea how to parse it back to Message ?

Comment: Ok I will check that

Answer (score 1):

I was able to save the output with the following function:

```
# Save output as JSON
def store_json(json_input):
    with open(json_file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write(json_input + '\n')
```

And as @dsesto mentioned, I had to define a dictionary. In this dictionary I have defined what types of information I would like to save in my output.

```
with open(photo_file, 'rb') as image:
    image_content = base64.b64encode(image.read())
    service_request = service.images().annotate(
        body={
            'requests': [{
                'image': {
                    'content': image_content
                },
                'features': [{
                    'type': 'LABEL_DETECTION',
                    'maxResults': 20,
                },
                    {
                        'type': 'TEXT_DETECTION',
                        'maxResults': 20,
                    },
                        {
                            'type': 'WEB_DETECTION',
                            'maxResults': 20,
                        }]
            }]
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

The objects in the current Vision library lack serialization functions (although this is a good idea).

It is worth noting that they are about to release a substantially different library for Vision (it is on master of vision's repo now, although not released to PyPI yet) where this will be possible. Note that it is a backwards-incompatible upgrade, so there will be some (hopefully not too much) conversion effort.

That library returns plain protobuf objects, which can be serialized to JSON using:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
serialized = MessageToJson(original)
```

You can also use something like [protobuf3-to-dict](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf3-to-dict/)